# Next week (April 26th) marks our 1-year anniversary! How should we celebrate it?

Tags: discussion

April 26th, 2016 was the first day of our private beta (and May 17 was the start of our public beta) which means that in a few days we will celebrate one year as a site!

Should we celebrate?

If so, how?

There are all sorts of possibilities both on-site and real-world. For example, perhaps we help drum up interest in the site by pushing ourselves to ask new questions and reward top questions and answers. Or, we could have a very A&C craft trade - sort of like a [secret Santa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secret_Santa) where we make a piece of art or craft and send it to a fellow user (would require some work to keep addresses private but we could figure something out).

What do you think?

How can we celebrate our first year as a site?

Answer (score 3):

It does feel like the site **should** have a physical, real world, craft event of some kind, otherwise it's all text and pictures, so as people here are from all over the world and unlikely to be able to get together in one location, that secret Santa idea is pretty cool. Reddit have had great success with that.

Comment: I can't remember which site did this but I got a real good feeling about it. Made the stack more "human" as best as I can describe it. Hell, if nothing else this could lead to more questions for A&C. "How did Matt make this part" etc.

Answer (score 1):

I think we could all celebrate together in chat - post our individual "birthday present". I'd be very interested to see what diverse ideas the comunity comes up with.

But instead of doing a secret santa *within* the comunity, we could then gift the results to someone we know and who might enjoy participating. I imagine something like a world-wide a "bring a friend" event.

And as a gift to the site, we could of course ask, answer and **vote** for new and existing questions.

(If next week is too soon to craft something, we might also choose the *public* beta date and give ourselves a longer deadline.)